# How to change font size only for the buffer *Org Export Dispatcher*?

Tags: org-export, buffers, osx, faces, fonts

I'm using emacs with a large font, however I do not need the font to be too large on certain buffers and/or modes. For example, when I use `neotree` I use a different font and a smaller size, I do that like this:

```
(add-hook 'neotree-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                              (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Hack" :height 130 :width semi-condensed))
                              (buffer-face-mode)))
```

I want to achieve the same thing but for the org export dispatch ui, that is, the buffer that appears when exporting an Org file (by using `org-export-dispatch`). While this window is active I can not use the `describe-mode` or see the `major-mode` so I don't know for which mode I should apply the settings.

I've tried this with no effect:

```
(defun my-buffer-face-mode-fixed ()
   (interactive)
   (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Hack" :height 130 :width semi-condensed))
   (buffer-face-mode))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-fixed)
```

As well as:

```
(add-hook 'org-export-stack-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-fixed)
```

It doesn't work.

What I was thinking was somehow set the font face for a buffer with a specific name, in that case the question is **how to change the font face for the `*Org Export Dispatcher*` buffer?**

While looking about how to change the font on a per name basis I found [this on the emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer#toc2):

```
 (set-specifier (face-background (get-face 'default)) "blue"
                (get-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

However the `set-specifier` function is only available in XEmacs, how can I achieve the same thing in GNU Emacs 26.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A glance on `org-export--dispatch-ui` shows that `org-export--dispatch-action` is the action right after generating the dispatch buffer. The function `org-export--dispatch-action` already handles the key-presses for the export options. Therefore you have no other choice than to put the font setting function before `org-export--dispatch-action` with the help of an advice.

```el
(defcustom org-export-dispatch-buffer-face '(:family "Hack" :height 130 :width semi-condensed)
  "The face specification used by `buffer-face-mode'.
It may contain any value suitable for a `face' text property,
including a face name, a list of face names, a face-attribute
plist, etc."
  :type '(choice (face)
         (repeat :tag "List of faces" face)
         (plist :tag "Face property list"))
  :group 'org-export)

(defun org-export-dispatch-set-font (&rest args)
  "Set font for Org Export Dispatch Buffer."
  (let ((buf (get-buffer "*Org Export Dispatcher*")))
    (when buf
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (apply #'buffer-face-set org-export-dispatch-buffer-face)))))

(advice-add 'org-export--dispatch-action :before #'org-export-dispatch-set-font)
```

Remark:
You could send a feature-request asking for a hook right before `org-export--dispatch-action` with the Export Dispatch Buffer as current buffer to the org-mode mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, it worked beautifully. As suggested I asked at the mailing list to add this hook.

Comment: @zzantares, did you ever hear back about this?

Comment: @apc hard to remember, but sadly it seems I never got a reply back.